# How to perform search operation in React with formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, formik

- here I have share screenshot, I want to perform search operation when type on that search box then only that row show e.g. when I type name then show only that row with edit or delete button
- I am new on this website, so help me.

[Refer this Link for img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRpPB.jpg)

- TableList.js
- share some screenshots of code

  [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adm5H.jpg)

  [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWWte.jpg)

  [image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3rlK.jpg)

  [image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1XDb.jpg)

  [image 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vul9l.jpg)

  [image 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0k4uY.jpg)